# Using List, how would I change this code as using List

Tags: java, arrays, collections

So I have this code at the bottom, and I have to Instantiate myArray to a new array. Copy all data from int[] data to myArray. Set numMoves equal to 0. data Array holding the values input from the user. So this code I have here is done by just using int and just = signs and new, But now I need to change this Using "List" and I do not know what list is and how to use it. So what I need help on is What is List on java and how would I do this using List. Thanks, and i prefer telling me how it works thank you!

```
 public class Deletions
{
private int[] myArray;
private int numMoves;

public Deletions(int[] data)
{
    myArray = new int [data.length] ;

    for(int n = 0; n < data.length; n++)
    {
        myArray[n] = data[n]; 
    }

    numMoves = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can find some info on lists [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Take a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface in Java. That means it can (and does) have many implementations. The two most basic are [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). How you would use them in this case is entirely dependent on your requirements. The simplest way would be to ditch the method altogether and use `new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.AsList(data))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, the original array copy method can be written like this.

```
    int[] myArray = new int[data.length];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, myArray, 0, data.length);
```

and then, the solution will be

```
public List<Integer> copyToList(int[] data){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        list.add(data[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

or

```
public List<Integer> copyFromToList(List<Integer> data){
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an ordered collection also known as Sequence. With ordered, it means that one can retrieve elements in the same Sequence as one has inserted the element into the List. Another important thing, List is interface not a concrete implementation. For concrete implementation, look at [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)/[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) etc.

To achieve the same result, I would write something like this:-

`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));`

Answer (score 1):

A *list* is any class whose instances can contain an ordered sequence of objects.

In Java, you most likely want to use `ArrayList<E>`, which is the *generic* list. Generic means that you can put whatever type of object in the list, as long as you specify that type (or one of its base types) in place of the `E`. An `ArrayList<E>` has methods such as `add`, `get`, and `set`.

For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(1337);
myList.add(42);
```

Look at the [`ArrayList<E>` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more information on what methods are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Deletions
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> myArray;
    private int numMoves;

    public Deletions(int[] data)
    {
        myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int n = 0; n < data.length; n++)
        {
            myArray.add(data[n]); 
        } 

        numMoves = 0;
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html